# this.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have JS below that i am trying to dispaly a menu item once the image is clicked under the image and once an item is clicked it disappears. i have multiple images that is why i am building this dynamic content menu. i am planning to add bunch of html element inside userMenuContent by

```
using var userMenuContent ="<div><form>...</<form></div>";
```

but to begin with my small test fails

```
function userMenu() {
    var userMenudiv = document.createElement("div");
    userMenudiv.setAttribute("class", "statusContainer");
     var userMenuContent = "<p>test</p>";
    $(userMenudiv).append($(userMenuContent));
    $(userMenudiv).hide();
    this.appendChild(userMenudiv);
    $(userMenudiv).slideDown();
}

    <img  class="icon" src="image.png" onclick="userMenu()"/>
```

when i click the image i get
 TypeError: this.appendChild is not a function.
i am using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui1.8.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'this' refers to the window object, not the image.

Don't use inline event handlers. Give the DOM element an id and select it that way.

You can't add a div to an image. Instead, you need to specify another target element

Since you're using jQuery, just do it the jQuery way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#userMenuImg').click(function(){

        $('#target')
            .append('<div class="statusContainer"><p>test</p></div>')
            .slideDown();

    });

});
<img id="userMenuImg" class="icon" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRMKbTxKTOJbJvVTt2SZak49lARNnCU4D7ECfZn1KspIn6SXDHz3A">

<div id="target"></div>
```

​
​

Comment: i am getting TypeError: n.createDocumentFragment is not a function with above code

Comment: That's because you can't append a div to an image. This was a literal adaptation of what I could sense from your sample code. Can you alliterate a bit on exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: when the user clciks on the image i was trying to dispaly a menu

Comment: i have muliple images not just one that is why i had created a function